# How can I make a relatively positioned parent that contains absolutely positioned children have 'flexible' height?

Tags: css

`<img>` (child) is absolutely centered within `.carousel` (parent). However, with responsive behavior, I would like to have `.carousel` (parent) have a height relative to the screen size and/or relative to the tallest `<img>`. Again, `<img>` height will vary depending on screen width.

```
.carousel {
  background: #dfe2e4;
  background: url(../images/bg/port-bg.png) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: 4px;
  min-height: 221px;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel img {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  /* 'Absolute' centering. */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

I think we can get this to work with JS, but using JS for styles sort of makes me cringe a little bit.

Comment: A carousel is a precarious balance of JS, CSS, and HTML, please provide a live demo which includes CSS and HTML by using jsFiddle, CodePen.io, the Snippet feature in the toolbar, etc...

Comment: Well, I'm not as worried about the JS for the carousel functionality. I would just like to have a CSS only way to at least have the .carousel (relatively positioned parent) maintain a proper height in the interest of responsive behavior. I know I can just put a fixed height and be done, and I can probably build a JS array of the children's heights, select the max and set the parent height accordingly, but was wondering about any other solution here (CSS only). I haven't done anything else with the build - just looking to solve this for now...thanks.

Comment: That's like asking a mechanic if there's anyway he could fix your car so it goes faster and you bring him a car with no engine.

Comment: Well..I think it might be more like I am going to do the engine and make it go faster, but I need the tech to gst the wheels lined mounted and lined up...or something. 